# How do I dynamically add an attr_reader

Tags: ruby

I expect the following code to work as expected but it gives me a NoMethodError (private method `foo' called for #<MyClass...)

```
class MyClass
end

my_object = MyClass.new

my_object.instance_variable_set(:@foo, "bar")
MyClass.send("attr_reader", :foo)

puts my_object.foo
```

The problem is I'm using literally identical code in a larger application and it works exactly as I expect, but when I simplify it to this most basic example it fails.

(I understand there are many other ways to do what I'm doing in Ruby)

Comment: The example works in irb but not ruby…

Comment: @jleedev - I found the same thing (both in Ruby 1.8.6 and Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7).  irb's great, but if you run the exact same commands from a file...  Do you think it's a bug in the Ruby implementation (REE mostly just redid the garbage collector)?

Answer (score 12):

Use [Module#class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000437):

By doing this, the block puts you in the context of MyClass, thus allowing you to call `attr_reader`

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :028 > my_object.instance_variable_set(:@foo, "bar")
 => "bar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :029 > MyClass.class_eval{attr_reader :foo}
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :030 > my_object.foo
 => "bar"
```

Comment: I wonder if one is able to do it for one particular instance of a class.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume for an instant that you want to create an accessor for that particular instance of the class (which I assume is the case since you are operating on the instance.

You can simply open up the instance's singleton class and use instance_eval to add the accessor

```
class MyClass
end
my_instance = MyClass.new
my_instance.singleton_class.instance_eval { attr_accessor :foo }
my_instance.foo = :bar
my_instance.foo # => :bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem, I found this solution works fine:

```
MyClass.class_eval("attr_reader :foo")
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the block form (per @MikeLewis' answer) rather than the string form so that no runtime parsing/lexing is needed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i just found this working solution quickly without searching for better ways.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @MikeLewis is nice, but why not just re-open the class?

```
irb(main):001:0> class MyClass; end
#=> nil
irb(main):002:0> m = MyClass.new
#=> #<MyClass:0x2d43ae0>
irb(main):003:0> class MyClass; attr_accessor :foo; end
#=> nil
irb(main):004:0> m.foo = 42
#=> 42
```

Comment: If it's a gem you're tweaking: `class ModuleName; end`

causes:

TypeError: ModuleName is not a class
 from (irb):15
 from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'`

Comment: @Crisfole perhaps because it's a `module` instead of a class.

Comment: I must have had a gem mix-up. I thought I was trying to re-open this -> https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail/blob/master/lib/gmail.rb#L3-L6. Maybe I forgot to run bundler....

Answer (score 0):

Just force the method to become public:

```
MyClass.send("public", :foo)
```

I have no idea why it is private in some cases.

Comment: This assumes that a `foo` method has already been defined, which may not be the case for some instance variables.

Comment: This is the best answer so far but I'm still curious as to why it private in some cases and not others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled at this, but one solution that works is to make the attribute_reader explicitly public using `MyClass.send(:public, :foo)`, i.e.

```
class MyClass
end

my_object = MyClass.new

my_object.instance_variable_set(:@foo, "bar")
MyClass.send(:attr_reader, :foo)
MyClass.send(:public, :foo)

puts my_object.foo
```